# Type mismatch when comparing cell and selected item from multicolumn list box

Tags: excel, vba

I am learning VBA, and this forum has helped me many times already, checking previous questions and answers, however this time I can't manage to figure out what is happening, and can't find an existing solution that works.

So, I have two listboxs in a worksheet: LB_SelectTaskToDelete and LB_SelectLineToDelete. The purpose of the first lisbox is to allow the user select a task, that later I will use in a macro to find it and delete it in another sheet.
Each task can be linked to one or more "Lines" so the second listbox lets the user select what specific Line he wants to delete, for a chosen Task. The code here is on the LB_SelectTaskToDelete  Change event, to fill the second listbox.

Before I was using LB_SelectTaskToDelete  with only one column, and this worked like a charm:

```
For Each cell In rng
If [cell.Value = LB_SelectTaskToDelete.Value] And [activetask = "Y"] Then LB_SelectLineToDelete.AddItem cell.Offset(0, 3).Value 
Next cell
```

But I wanted to give more info to the user adding a second column, and now I don't know how to make it work.

Currently looks like this, but I keep getting Type mismatch error.

```
If LB_SelectTaskToDelete.ListIndex > -1 And LB_SelectTaskToDelete.Selected(LB_SelectTaskToDelete.ListIndex) Then
    For Each cell In rng
    activetask = CStr(cell.Offset(0, -2).Value)
    selectedTask = CStr(LB_SelectTaskToDelete.List(LB_SelectTaskToDelete.ListIndex, 0))
    celltext = CStr(cell.Text)
    If [celltext = selectedtask] Then MsgBox ("Works") ' Should be an And with the two statements
    If [activetask = "Y"] Then MsgBox ("works too") 'LB_SelectLineToDelete.AddItem cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
    Next cell
End If
```

The error appears on

```
If [celltext = selectedtask] Then
```

The text saved in the variables is like this: "PM001"
If both are strings, why the type mismatch?

Comment: Why are you using square brackets? Remove them and you should be fine.

Comment: I would always recommend making sure you do data validation prior to doing checks on data of different types. Here activetask is being read in as a value and then compared to a string. Also selectedTask value to celltext string. I, personally, try to avoid taking direct "value" and instead try to define the data type on the way into the variable.

Comment: Initially the code had both statements of the if in the same line, with And. To separate them  and the "And" in the middle, I commonly use brackets. I forgot to take them out when putting on new line.

Comment: The three variables are defined as strings (activetask , selectedtask , celltext). How can I do the data validation? that's new to me